# Writing to a Named Pipe not showing the full content of a string

Tags: c, named-pipes

I am trying to read data from 2 named pipe and write it to another named pipe concatenating the content from 2 inputs. But why my output only shows the string from first input?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_REC_SIZE 1024

int open_fifo(char *name, int mode) {
   mode = mode == O_RDONLY ? (O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK): mode;
   int fd;
   if (access(name, F_OK) == -1) {
      if(mkfifo(name, 0777) != 0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Could not create fifo %s\n", name);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   }
   fd = open(name, mode);;
   return fd;
}

void read_fifo(int fd, char *out_r) {
   memset (out_r, '\0', MAX_REC_SIZE);
   do {
      if(read(fd, out_r, MAX_REC_SIZE) > 0) {
         out_r = strtok(out_r, "\n");
         return;
      }
   } while (1);
}

void write_fifo(int fd, char *out_w) {
    write(fd, out_w, sizeof(out_w));
}

int main()
{
   int pipe_fd[3], i;
   char *pipe_nm[] = {"./in_pipe_1", "./in_pipe_2", "./out_pipe_1"};
   int read_mode = O_RDONLY;
   int write_mode = O_WRONLY;
   char out[MAX_REC_SIZE];
   char out_store[MAX_REC_SIZE];

   for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
      pipe_fd[i] = open_fifo(pipe_nm[i], i == 2 ? write_mode : read_mode);
   }

   read_fifo(pipe_fd[0], out);
   strcpy(out_store, out);
   read_fifo(pipe_fd[1], out);
   strcat(out_store, out);
   strcat(out_store, "\n");
   write_fifo(pipe_fd[2], out_store);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: Don't understand why many people prefer `memset (out_r, '\0', MAX_REC_SIZE);` instead of clean `memset (out_r, 0, MAX_REC_SIZE);`. Maybe they think that '\0' is different than 0.

Comment: @i486: He would be even better off initialising it when declaring: `char out[MAX_REC_SIZE] = {0}`.

Comment: @i486 Some people prefer to use a character literal to indicate that the value is to be interpreted as a character as opposed to a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suspicious part of your code is:

```
write(fd, out_w, sizeof(out_w))
```

Here, `out_w` is not an array, and the `sizeof` operator would yield the size of a `char *` pointer, not the length of the block.

You should pass the length of `out_store` to your `write_fifo` function.

Also, I'm not really sure what your intent is when using the `strtok` function.

Comment: ...Or simply use `strlen`.

Comment: Sir, is `out_r = strtok(out_r, "\n");` inside `read_fifo()` is ok? i mean isn't it like it will discard the `out_r` after returning or am I missing something?

Comment: strtok is used to simply discard the trailing "\n".

Comment: Replacing sizeof with strlen solved my problem. Thanks.